# Limit of argmin of sum

Tags: riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, convexity, convex-optimization, global-optimization

Suppose that I know $f_n\rightarrow f$ and $g_n\rightarrow g$ are both continuous maps from a Complete Riemmanian Manifold $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which converge pointwise almost everywhere.  Then is it true that:
\begin{equation}
argmin_{x \in X} (f+g) = \lim_{n\mapsto \infty} argmin_{x \in X} (f_n+g_n)\,?
\end{equation}

Comment: You have to give more details on the convergence $f_n\to f$. Also what do you mean by $\DeclareMathOperator{\amin}{argmin}$   $\amin_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\sin x$?

Comment: $argmin_{x\in \mathbb{R}}sin(x)=\{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi:k \in \mathbb{N}\}$... I never assumed the argmin function took unique (or non-empty) values....

Comment: With only  pointwise convergence I doubt you can say something meaningful. Also  you need to define the motion of convergence of sets that you have in mind since, according your comment argmin is a st.

Comment: You should look up the notion of Gamma convergence.

Comment: I did a few days after posting this; that's exactly what I used since my functions were l.s.c.